# New Pi Zero W brcmfmac failures and can't start wlan0 WiFi

Tags: wifi, wireless, pi-zero-w

I have to set this up headless because I didn't realize the Zero W had mini HDMI and not micro.

So I flashed both the 2017-04-10 Raspbian light and full from Linux (with dd) and then mounted the FAT partition and dropped in the `ssh` file and a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file (see below) and booted it.  I've tried dozens of other ways of configuring it including changes to `/etc/network/interfaces` and so on (including `wireless-power off`) but no matter what, whenever I remount the card later to view `/var/log/syslog` it always has the same failure pattern:

```
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.091048] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.512291] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: May 27 2016 00:13:38 version 7.45.41.26 (r640327) FWID 01-df77e4a7
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [    8.565794] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473404] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_reg_notifier: not a ISO3166 code
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473440] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473450] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473460] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473474] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473488] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz, 92000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473499] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473513] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473525] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473536] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473546] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   10.473557] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   12.357882] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.673973] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_kso_control: max tries: rd_val=0x0 err=0
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674038] brcmfmac: brcmf_proto_bcdc_query_dcmd: brcmf_proto_bcdc_msg failed w/status -110
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674166] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674348] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674527] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674668] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674767] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.674955] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.675116] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_txfail: sdio error, abort command and terminate frame
Apr 10 10:09:45 raspberrypi kernel: [   15.675251] brcmfmac: brcmf_sdio_dpc: failed backplane access over SDIO, halting operation
```

And then later during boot:

```
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: if_up: Input/output error
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi dhcpcd[376]: wlan0: waiting for carrier
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Input/output error
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: nl80211: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: Could not set interface wlan0 flags (UP): Input/output error
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: WEXT: Could not set interface 'wlan0' UP
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi wpa_supplicant[373]: wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi ifup[347]: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: 120: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant: cannot create /dev/stderr: No such device or address
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi ifup[347]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Apr 10 10:09:54 raspberrypi ifup[347]: Failed to bring up wlan0.
```

(Those timestamps are nonsense because it's never had the time set properly, of course.)

I am using a quality 2A power supply and my `wpa_supplicant.conf` (installed via `/boot` copying or manually) currently looks like this (I doubt this matters since the driver is failing early):

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
network={
    ssid="YSN2"
    psk="<plaintext not shown>"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I tried smaller and larger such files until I noticed the lower-level errors.

I've reflashed multiple times, rebooted many times, etc.

I've tried Philip Ashmore's answer but it just seems to clean up the logs; the root problem appears to be the driver errors about "sdio" and the -110 timeouts.

I've tried the older `2017-03-02-raspbian-jessie-lite` release as well and the logs are the same.

Is my device faulty?  Is the latest firmware broken (the OS image I used is 2 months old, so I hope not)?

Comment: did you ever solve this issue? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: No. I eventually assumed my hardware was broken (or the software is not very robust against minor variations) and gave up. The Pi Zero W remains in a box, unused.

Comment: I have had the same issue, and can't get it to work either. Tried a bunch of stuff. Very rarely the wlan0 device turns up, but then it still doesn't work. I am guessing hardware problems too..... :(

Comment: It may indeed be a dud due to wrong programming in the factory. See https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/no-wifi-bluetooth-on-pi0w-v1-1/5026/3. Will check if that is my issue too.

Answer (score 0):

While setting up Debian Stretch on my laptop I came across the same problem.

I Googled wpa_supplicant /dev/stderr and found
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838291

If you're doing something similar I also had a problem with apt-key - I needed to install dirmngr

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ha! You answered this literally 30 seconds after I ordered a $0.99 mini HDMI adapter from ebay. :)  Well at least I probably don't need to wait from shipping until August to set it up now!

Comment: Doing this fixed the /dev/stderr noise in the logs, but I think the root problem is the script had reached the point where it wanted to log an error :).  Now I get the same sdio and other errors, but a simple `Apr 10 10:10:05 raspberrypi ifup[342]: wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start`.  However it does point me in the right direction.

Comment: That was a dead end, it seems.  I think the root cause is closer to the sdio errors from the driver.

Comment: Please read the original question. He was asking about wifi on a raspberry pi zero. Your answer has absolutely nothing to do with the question.